# asp .net/click once application issue

Tags: asp.net, clickonce

So we are trying to run this click once application on Server 2003 with IIS6. It works on some systems and not this one. The systems all have the exact same files as far as the dlls and deployment files. Here is one of the errors we are getting. Any help would be appriciated, been working on this for over a month now.

> Server Error in '/ODBWebService' Application.
>
> The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x8007007E)  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the
>   execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace
>   for more information about the error and where it originated in the
>   code.
>
> Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The specified
>   module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [FileNotFoundException: The specified module could not be found.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)]
>   System.Reflection.Assembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String
>   codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly locationHint,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean
>   forIntrospection) +0    System.Reflection.Assembly.nLoad(AssemblyName
>   fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly
>   locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound,
>   Boolean forIntrospection) +43
>   System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(AssemblyName assemblyRef,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean
>   forIntrospection) +127
>   System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean
>   forIntrospection) +142    System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String
>   assemblyString) +28
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String
>   assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +46
>
> [ConfigurationErrorsException: The specified module could not be
>   found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)]
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String
>   assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +613
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory()
>   +203    System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo
>   ai) +105
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection
>   compConfig) +178
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler..ctor(VirtualPath
>   configPath, Boolean supportLocalization, String outputAssemblyName)
>   +54    System.Web.Compilation.CodeDirectoryCompiler.GetCodeDirectoryAssembly(VirtualPath
>   virtualDir, CodeDirectoryType dirType, String assemblyName, StringSet
>   excludedSubdirectories, Boolean isDirectoryAllowed) +8812914
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileCodeDirectory(VirtualPath
>   virtualDir, CodeDirectoryType dirType, String assemblyName, StringSet
>   excludedSubdirectories) +128
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileResourcesDirectory() +31
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled() +304
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): The specified module could not be found.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)]
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ReportTopLevelCompilationException()
>   +58    System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled() +512
>   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager
>   appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory
>   configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters)
>   +729
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): The specified module could not be found.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +8894223 
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +85
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpWorkerRequest wr)
>   +259
>
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.3625;
>   ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.3618

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't just dump stacktraces and error messages. Try to formulate a question. And please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention anything about what framework version this is on.
But it seems that you are using some HTTP calls, and therefore I trow this stab in the dark:

Are you by any chance running .NET 3.5/4.0 Client Profile instead of the full framework on this machine?

Are by any chance doing interop?
Do you distribute the native DLL?

Otherwise a brute force troubleshooting method would be to fire up Process Monitor and look for file not found errors for the given process.

Comment: The framework version is 2.0. I have 3.5 and 4 installed but this app and the app pool are set to run as 2.0.  I also get this error in the event log... <BR> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 3.199.183.164:2202. 3.199.183.164 is my servers IP address. How can it not access itself? Could this be a DNS resolution error? Shouldnt 3.199.183.164 resolve to 127.0.0.1 if its my own address?

Comment: Ok, I'm confused, can you please explain the relationship between ClickOnce and IIs in your question? Do you have a ClickOnce app and a Web App? Which of them experience this exception?

Comment: It is a click once application that we place on our server that gets deployed to other terminals. This click once app uses asp.net 2.0 in event log we keep getting an asp .net 2.0 error every time we try to run it.(just posted it above) so I am assuming that they are related.

Comment: Event Log Error - ASP.NET 2.0.50727.0 System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 3.199.183.164:2202. 3.199.183.164 is my servers IP address. How can it not access itself? Could this be a DNS resolution error? Shouldnt 3.199.183.164 resolve to 127.0.0.1 if its my own address?

Comment: Wow, you do bring a lot of extra information in to your comments that should be in the question. Further, you **really need to clarify your setup here**. Where is this ClickOnce app running? On clients or on the server? Is the exception you mention in your question happening on the  ClickOnce app or the Web App?

Comment: Its running on the server, but im not sure if the error exception is from the click once app or the web app, how can i tell??

Comment: I found it. Thanks for your help though. It was a .dll that was making a call to other .dll that it couldnt find. I downloaded a .dll dependency scanner and found that.